# HTML table does not appear as I want it to be

Tags: html

I have a problem wanting to make an HTML table since when trying to do it appears in many squares and I want it at the end of all. To understand better attached two images of how I appear currently and how I want it.

As it is currently:

[image: badphoto]

How it should be:

[image: photo2]

**HTML**

```html
<t t-foreach="i.detalle_documento_ids" t-as="o">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span t-esc="o.cuenta_id.titulo" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span t-esc="o.fecha" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span t-esc="o.razon_social_id.nombre" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span t-esc="o.total_debe" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span t-esc="o.total_haber" />
    </td>
    <th>
     <td colspan="3" align="center">Saldo</td>
      <td colspan="2"><b>Proxim</b></td>
    </th>
  </tr>
</t>
```

Comment: TH is not a valid parent for TD. It is INSTEAD of TD and should be children of TR

Comment: `<tr><th colspan="3" align="center">Saldo</th>    <th colspan="2"><b>Proxim</b>    </th></tr>`

Comment: Voting to close this since _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: with this:<tr><th colspan="3" align="center">Saldo</th> <th colspan="2"><b>Proxim</b> </th></tr>

It appears to me as follows:
https://ibb.co/jvYw3Gn   .The way I want it to remain is still not created :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must create new **balance table tr** after the **loop table**  or in **tfooter** section of current table